# missing data for column "stusab"

Tags: postgresql

Can't resolve this issue. Link to dataset- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anthonydb/practical-sql/main/Chapter_04/us_counties_2010.csv

[image]

I used

```
CREATE TABLE us_counties_2010 (
NAME VARCHAR(255),  
STUSAB  VARCHAR(255),
SUMLEV  VARCHAR(255),
REGION  smallint,
DIVISION smallint,  
STATE   VARCHAR(255),
COUNTY  VARCHAR(255),
AREALAND bigint,    
AREAWATR bigint,    
POP100  integer,
HU100   integer,
INTPTLAT numeric(10,7),
INTPTLON numeric(10,7),
P0010001 integer,
P0010002 integer,
P0010003 integer,
P0010004 integer, 
P0010005 integer,
P0010006 integer,
P0010007 integer, 
P0010008 integer,
P0010009 integer, 
P0010010 integer, 
P0010011 integer, 
P0010012 integer,
P0010013 integer,   
P0010014 integer,
P0010015 integer,
P0010016 integer,
P0010017 integer,   
P0010018 integer,   
P0010019 integer,   
P0010020 integer,   
P0010021 integer,   
P0010022 integer,   
P0010023 integer,   
P0010024 integer,   
P0010025 integer,   
P0010026 integer,   
P0010047 integer,   
P0010063 integer,   
P0010070 integer,   
P0020002 integer,   
P0020003 integer,   
P0020004 integer,   
P0020005 integer,   
P0020006 integer,   
P0020007 integer,   
P0020008 integer,   
P0020009 integer,   
P0020010 integer,   
P0020011 integer,   
P0020012 integer,   
P0020028 integer,   
P0020049 integer,   
P0020065 integer,   
P0020072 integer,   
P0030001 integer,   
P0030002 integer,   
P0030003 integer,   
P0030004 integer,   
P0030005 integer,   
P0030006 integer,   
P0030007 integer,   
P0030008 integer,   
P0030009 integer,   
P0030010 integer,   
P0030026 integer,   
P0030047 integer,   
P0030063 integer,   
P0030070 integer,   
P0040001 integer,   
P0040002 integer,   
P0040003 integer,   
P0040004 integer,   
P0040005 integer,   
P0040006 integer,   
P0040007 integer,   
P0040008 integer,   
P0040009 integer,   
P0040010 integer,   
P0040011 integer,   
P0040012 integer,   
P0040028 integer,   
P0040049 integer,   
P0040065 integer,   
P0040072 integer,   
H0010001 integer,   
H0010002 integer,   
H0010003 integer
);
```

Comment: The copy command you used would be more useful here.

Comment: I used /COPY us_counties_2010
FROM 'C:\Users\ariyi\OneDrive\Documents\Software\SQL\Counties.txt'
WITH delimiter ',' header csv;

Comment: Your table DDL defines 90 columns while the dataset does have 91. Hence "extra data after ..."

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you. Mind if I ask, is there a way to know how many columns you have in the dataset, so this can be compared with the one in the create table?

Comment: Copy the header line of the dataset, paste it into a text editor, replace `,` with newline character and see the number of lines. It takes a few seconds. You can further use these lines to create the DDL. That's how I quickly wrote the DDL in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted a column in your table DDL. Use this one & it works.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS us_counties_2010;
CREATE TABLE us_counties_2010
(
NAME text,  
STUSAB  text,
SUMLEV  text,
REGION  smallint,
DIVISION smallint,  
STATE   text,
COUNTY  text,
AREALAND bigint,    
AREAWATR bigint,    
POP100  integer,
HU100   integer,
INTPTLAT numeric(10,7),
INTPTLON numeric(10,7),
P0010001 integer,
P0010002 integer,
P0010003 integer,
P0010004 integer,
P0010005 integer,
P0010006 integer,
P0010007 integer,
P0010008 integer,
P0010009 integer,
P0010010 integer,
P0010011 integer,
P0010012 integer,
P0010013 integer,
P0010014 integer,
P0010015 integer,
P0010016 integer,
P0010017 integer,
P0010018 integer,
P0010019 integer,
P0010020 integer,
P0010021 integer,
P0010022 integer,
P0010023 integer,
P0010024 integer,
P0010025 integer,
P0010026 integer,
P0010047 integer,
P0010063 integer,
P0010070 integer,
P0020001 integer,
P0020002 integer,
P0020003 integer,
P0020004 integer,
P0020005 integer,
P0020006 integer,
P0020007 integer,
P0020008 integer,
P0020009 integer,
P0020010 integer,
P0020011 integer,
P0020012 integer,
P0020028 integer,
P0020049 integer,
P0020065 integer,
P0020072 integer,
P0030001 integer,
P0030002 integer,
P0030003 integer,
P0030004 integer,
P0030005 integer,
P0030006 integer,
P0030007 integer,
P0030008 integer,
P0030009 integer,
P0030010 integer,
P0030026 integer,
P0030047 integer,
P0030063 integer,
P0030070 integer,
P0040001 integer,
P0040002 integer,
P0040003 integer,
P0040004 integer,
P0040005 integer,
P0040006 integer,
P0040007 integer,
P0040008 integer,
P0040009 integer,
P0040010 integer,
P0040011 integer,
P0040012 integer,
P0040028 integer,
P0040049 integer,
P0040065 integer,
P0040072 integer,
H0010001 integer,
H0010002 integer,
H0010003 integer
);

COPY us_counties_2010 FROM 'path\to\the_dataset.txt' WITH delimiter ',' header csv;

-- Updated Rows 3143
```